# Using Pythons shutil to create a directory if it does not already exist?

Tags: python

I have a program that currently copies a file from my computer to other computers on the network.  This functions just fine if the other computers already have the directory specified.

Some of the computers may not already have the specified directory.  In this case, how could I create the directory if it does not exist and then copy the file into the new directory.  Would shutil.copytree() work?

Here is a portion of my current program

```
import fileinput
import shutil

def copyerror():
    print (" //////////////////////////////////////////")
    print (" ")
    print (" Cannot connect to " + servername + ".")
    print (" ")
    print (" //////////////////////////////////////////")   

def copyfiles(servername):
    source = os.listdir("C:/Users/jm/Desktop/PythonUpdate/") 
    destination = '//' + servername + '/c$/test/' 
    for files in source:
        if files.endswith(".config"):
            try:
                shutil.copy(files,destination)
            except:
                copyerror()


array = []
with open("C:/Users/jm/Desktop/PythonUpdate/serverlist.txt", "r") as f:
    for servername in f:

        copyfiles(servername.strip())
```

So if the /test directory doesnt exist, I want to go ahead and create one.

**UPDATE**
Also, is there a method I could use to stop the copying of the file to the new computer?  That's if the directory does not already exist.

Comment: `import os; os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)` https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html#os.makedirs

Comment: can I place that after shutil.copy(files,destination) ?

Comment: oops i posted in wrong place

Answer (score 0):

No, if the directory doesn't exist how can you copy the file into the directory? Create the directory or check if it already exists and then copy the file

Comment: Do you think it would be better to place it after the destination = '//' + servername + '/c$/test/' line or the 'try:' in the if statement?  I see it works in both but I'm also already checking for errors in the 'try:' so that may be better?  I could make a second try-catch block but I'm thinking I can keep my code simpler by keeping it all in the original try-catch block.  I know I should elaborate on the 'try' block and probably check for different errors.